# having trouble using the angular.module directive to create a new module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-module

I am having trouble using  the angular.module directive to create a new module. here is the code to create the module:

```
   angular.module('dcuapp', [])
          .config(dcuRouter);
    function dcuRouter($routeProvider){
       $routeProvider
         .when('/', {templateUrl: 'PARTIALS/left-panel.html'});
     }
```

the error I get is "angular is undefinded", invalid or non-existent $routeProvider

I am following the code from a Lynda.com course, I even changed the name of the module to be the same as the course = "airline" to no avail...

I have looked for missing commas, periods, braces, square brackets, angle brackets, parenthersis and matching double quotes and single quotes. the thing is the code is so short what else can I be missing.

I have also checked for missing SCRIPT TAGS, LINK HREF TAGS and nothing.... nyet, nada.... which makes using angular very frustrating....

anywho: any help will be greatly appreciated. in the mean time i'll keep looking for MY mistake...
:(

Answer (score 0):

The $routeProvider is part of a separate module (`ngRoute`) since angular 1.2, that must be added to the scripts, and to the dependencies of your module. See the [official documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

Comment: done that; added the file angular-route.js to the script sr= list and added the ['ntRoute'] string to the module giving me "angular.module('dcuapp', ['ntRoute']) with the same results.

Comment: the [] is ['ngRoute']

Comment: Post the code you're using now, by editing your question, and the exact anc complete error message.